# How to crawl dates in pinterest

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, pinterest

I want to crawl by searching for a specific keyword on the pinterest site.
However, the date the post was created is not visible when logged in.
How can I view or crawl the date the post was created??(I use python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, front end normally won't have time of when that posts was created, however I have found a way that you scrape that post's id from DOM(it is available with attribute `data-test-id="pin"`) and make a GET request separately to a URL(using python's [request](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)). Here's this example of that [URL](https://in.pinterest.com/resource/OffsiteLinkResource/get/?source_url=%2Fpin%2F55943220361107824%2F&data=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22check_only%22%3Atrue%2C%22client_tracking_params%22%3A%22CwABAAAAEDU5NTIzOTIwOTkwMDMwODQA%7E0%22%2C%22pin_id%22%3A%2255943220361107824%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Ftrip101.com%2Farticle%2Fbe-bowled-over-by-beauty-at-india-s-iconic-taj-mahal%22%2C%22no_fetch_context_on_resource%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22context%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&_=1607921241507).
This URL will give details about the post in JSON format, which will have time of its creation.

You can concatenate strings and generate URL like

```
protocol+"//"+domain+"/resource/PinResource/get/?source_url=/pin/"+post_id+"/&data={%22options%22:{%22id%22:"+'"'+post_id+"%22,%22field_set_key%22:%22detailed%22,%22is_landing_page%22:false},%22context%22:{}}&_=1523412899257"
```

You can get protocol and domain like(in python selenium):

```
protocol = driver.execute_script("return document.location.protocol")
```

```
domain = driver.execute_script("return document.location.hostname")
```

Comment: Then that '''protocol+"//"+domain+"/resource/PinResource/get/?source_url=/pin/"+post_id+"/&data={%22options%22:{%22id%22:"+'"'+post_id+" %22,%22field_set_key%22:%22detailed%22,%22is_landing_page%22:false},%22context%22:{}}&_=1523412899257"''' Is the first created_at the date the post was created after entering the link?

Comment: Sorry man, I don't think so it works as I thought. Pinterest doesn't shows date of pins anymore. Its not present in either their API :(

createdAt represents about the current user

Comment: If so, what does date_published represent?

Comment: I don't see such attribute in my response. Maybe this feature is country specific that means it will not work for IN,US but may work for other countries. Date published is I guess date at which post was created

Comment: Is there any way to connect without using selenium?

Comment: @skw0314 what do you mean by that?

Comment: When I get the protocol and domain, I use the driver. Can I get the URL without using it? (To use only requests without using selenium)

Comment: Yeah, if your crawler is only 1 country specific. I used protocol and domain because every country have different domain.right?. So, I am from India so my domain would be ```in.pinterest.com``` but if you're from different country your domain would definitely be different. So, as per your country, you can hard-code that domain and make request.

Comment: Can Instagram know the url according to the post id like Pinterest? (like: protocol+"//"+domain+"/resource/PinResource/get/?source_url=/pin/"+post_id+"/&data={%22options %22:{%22id%22:"+'"'+post_id+"%22,%22field_set_key%22:%22detailed%22,%22is_landing_page%22:false},%22context%22:{}}&_=1523412899257" )

Comment: Instagram URL does not works with ```post_id``` attribute it rather works with ```shortcode```. Their URL pattern is ```https://instagram.com/p/{shortcode}``` . You can get shortcode from their grapql API. example [here](https://instagram.com/p/B7NOFZzHksY) . If you want single post's data, you won't get, but you will get data based on either hashtag or profile. Suppose you want to scrap posts from [this](https://www.instagram.com/bts.bighitofficial/) than you will get post's detail in a collection not based on single